# Can we quantify the benefit of convolutional coding or does it just work well in practice?

Tags: coding-theory

Convolutional coding is often applied in wireless transmission systems since it allows for [economical maximum likelihood soft decision decoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_code) in contrast to older channel codings. While I intitively see a qualitative advantage of this, I am not able to formulate a quantitative statement about the benefit and also the statements I can find are very vague. For example:

> Since a convolutional code doesn't use blocks, processing instead a
>   continuous bitstream, the value of t applies to a quantity of errors
>   located relatively near to each other. That is, multiple groups of t
>   errors can usually be fixed when they are relatively far apart. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_code#Free_distance_and_error_distribution)

*Is this all we can get? Is modern coding theory just trial-and-error? If not, it should be possible to formulate any qualitative statement about the following concrete example.*

### Exemplary Comparison

Let's consider the following transmission chain. We have a stream of bits with a given bit rate (e.g. $1\,\text{Mb/s}$). Then we apply a coding as given below to transfer the stream of bits to a stream of chips (just a placeholder term to avoid the confusion of bits and bits). These chips are then modulated and transmitted over a wireless channel. At the receiver, we have a demodulator that reconstructs the stream of chips. Due to the transmission and depending on the modulation some chips are erroneously flipped. Then decoding is applied to transfer the stream of chips back to a stream of bits. Depending on the errors in the stream of chips and the coding we now have some errors in the bits.

As a simple example and to explain what I want to achieve, let's consider a $n=3$ [repetition code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_code). Assuming that the probability for a chip error is $p$ and that they are independent and identically distributed. Then after decoding ([also see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_logic_decoding#Theory)) the probability for a bit error is
\begin{equation*}
{3 \choose 2} p^2 (1-p)^1 + {3 \choose 3} p^3 = 3p^2-2p^3.
\end{equation*}

- *Interposed question:* Is this correct and is the statement of iid chip errors equivalent to saying that we have a memoryless AWGN channel?

In the same scenario let's consider three other codings.

**1. A convolutional code with the following generator polynomials¹**

\begin{equation*}
G_0(x) = 1+x+x^2+x^3\\
G_1(x) = 1+x^2+x^3
\end{equation*}

Afterward, with `a_0` being the result of the first polynomial and `a_1` being the one of the second, the following mapping is applied resulting in 8 chips:

```
| a_0 | a_1 |  output  |
|-----|-----|----------|
|  0  |  0  | 00110011 |
|  1  |  0  | 11000011 |
|  0  |  1  | 00111100 |
|  1  |  1  | 11001100 |
```

**2. A mapping of 4 consecutive bits to 32 chips according to the following table²**

```
| input  |             output               |
|--------|----------------------------------|
|  0000  | 11011001110000110101001000101110 |
|  0001  | 11101101100111000011010100100010 |
|  0010  | 00101110110110011100001101010010 |
|  0011  | 00100010111011011001110000110101 |
|  0100  | 01010010001011101101100111000011 |
|  0101  | 00110101001000101110110110011100 |
|  0110  | 11000011010100100010111011011001 |
|  0111  | 10011100001101010010001011101101 |
|  1000  | 10001100100101100000011101111011 |
|  1001  | 10111000110010010110000001110111 |
|  1010  | 01111011100011001001011000000111 |
|  1011  | 01110111101110001100100101100000 |
|  1100  | 00000111011110111000110010010110 |
|  1101  | 01100000011101111011100011001001 |
|  1110  | 10010110000001110111101110001100 |
|  1111  | 11001001011000000111011110111000 |
```

**3. A trivial repetition code**

```
| input  |  output  |
|--------|----------|
|   0    | 00000000 |
|   1    | 11111111 |
```

In the end, for all methods, the chip rate is 8 times the bit rate.

- Still assuming iid chip errors and demodulation with a hard decision for chips that either are 0 or 1 before the decoding, does the probability of an error in the final bit stream depend on the coding?
- What changes if we apply a more realistic channel model and/or soft-decision decoders and how can one quantify the resulting difference of the methods?
- Is the ability to perform soft decision the only benefit of convolutional coding, even compared to trivial repetition codes?

<sub>¹LE Coded PHY with S=8 in Bluetooth 5, ²IEEE 802.15.4 DSSS.</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The bit errors happen inside the channel (the input to the channel is the output of the encoder), hence the bit error rate is not related to the channel encoding, Things would be different only for those cases which combine channel coding and modulation (see Trellis modulation http://www.invocom.et.put.poznan.pl/~invocom/C/P1-7/en/P1-7/p1-7_7_1.htm)

Comment: Also, to speak of "bit error rate" in the case of soft-decision makes little or no sense to me.

Comment: @leonbloy Sorry, I was imprecise with the notation. With bit error rate I meant errors in the bitstream after decoding. I hope the edit helps to clarify this. I now denote the "original bits before coding" as bits and the "transmitted bits after coding" as chips. If you have a better idea, I welcome your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a simple example. Say you are sending $n$ bits. Each of them is repeated $3$ times. Ok $3n$ bits now and so divide it into $k$ chips per sec.Let's say some errors happen here. You are transmitting finally $k$ chips. The channel corrupts those bits and for *each* chip the final probability is $p$ including the combined modulation, demodulation and channel errors.They are independent so shouldn't  $p^k$ be the combined probability? The link you mentioned says "$\epsilon$  is the error over the transmission channel" which doesn't cover the coding/decoding and modulation/demodulation method errors.

So

- Still assuming iid chip errors and demodulation with a hard decision for chips that either are 0 or 1 before the decoding, does the probability of an error in the final bit stream depend on the coding?

$Answer$: I'd say No. It is more likely that the transmission caused the bit flip than the coding method which is most likely local and easily error corrected.

- What changes if we apply a more realistic channel model and/or soft-decision decoders and how can one quantify the resulting difference of the methods?

$Answer$: This shouldn't matter at all if you know $p$ which is the final probability at the receiving end.

Comment: Thank you! So your answer basically is that channel coding has no influence on the probability of errors? Wouldn't that imply that channel coding is useless at all? Also regarding your last part, isn't it impossible to provide a single p if the errors are not iid?

Comment: Practically, what I meant to say is that probability of errors due to the channel outweighs any changes to error correction algorithms at the decoder and the encoder. BT spec. suggests 1/3 and 2/3 rate FEC and using Turbo coding which uses the Soft-Decision decoders, BER, the probability of the error must be kept below 0.1% and that's about it. The probability varies as the receiver moves around(Headsets for e,g). Is IID even applicable? Most of the BT chip vendors tend towards similar implementation and tweak ECC algorithms but stick to high performing ECC at the end in dense environments...

Comment: What does "high performing" then means in the context of ECCs? Why do they use high performing ECC if the choice of the ECC is irrelevant due to the volatile channel as you write?

Comment: By high performance I meant the delay in decoding is lesser. Depending on the code you use say Soft or Hard-decision. etc. See the comparison here http://www.arl.army.mil/arlreports/2009/ARL-TR-4901.pdf